# Apache - extremely slow initial handshake (SSL enabled)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have a problem with Apache server. The initial SSL handshake takes about 5-7 seconds which is horrible. After that the response time is in miliseconds - but the messages must be sent right after the first one or the handshake will be done again after a few seconds of inactivity. Is there any way to speed it up with Apache configuration?

Answer (score 6):

This is with some Linux distro, right?

Is this server mostly idle? Perhaps Apache is shoveling randomness from */dev/random*. That can be sometimes very slow, since */dev/random* requires "real" randomness; stuff like moving the mouse, using the keyboard and network traffic gather the entropy. If the kernel entropy pool is nearly empty, processes requiring randomness tend to stall for a (long) while.

Should this be the situation, `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` should be near zero during SSL handshake.

You may switch the randomness source to */dev/urandom* by using [`SSLRandomSeed`Apache directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrandomseed), but be warned, this is theoretically not as secure as /dev/random.

Other solution is to use daemon like `rngd` (available from `rng-tools` package in many Linux distros) which fills up entropy pool.

Comment: No change with `/dev/urandom`. I don't have `rng-tools` and `tcpdump` from the post below available and because I'm not the server's admin I can't install it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Janne Pikkarainen said, check also if the server is not doing a DNS reverse lookup for SSL requests. Run a `tcpdump -pi eth0 port 53`.