# Suddenly start getting err_connection_reset

Tags: apache-2.4, connection, xampp

Suddenly I started to get the `net::err_connection_reset 200`. It only happens in one page of my site, all the other pages load fine. I removed everything from the controller and model and only left the essential functions to the page load. After that I removed all the content from the page and still get the same error. All the scripts loads, but the page fails to load. [image: fail]

[image]
these are the logs from the apache after page load with error

```
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.355859 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14224:tid 580] AH00428: Parent: child process 8768 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.529036 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 14224:tid 580] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.568924 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14224:tid 580] AH00455: Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.4.21 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.568924 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14224:tid 580] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: May 26 2021 14:28:02
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.568924 2021] [core:notice] [pid 14224:tid 580] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp2\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp2/apache'
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.578898 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14224:tid 580] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14236
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.830031 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 14236:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.860471 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 14236:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jul 26 12:10:48.885405 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14236:tid 588] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I'm stuck on this for the past 2 days. It started to happen after I run am insert query to the DB. I'm using XAMPP, PHP 7.4, on Windows 10.

Already read [IIS 8 ERR_CONNECTION_RESET](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067042/iis-8-err-connection-reset) [random CONNECTION_RESET on apache2.4 debian 9](https://serverfault.com/questions/893905/random-connection-reset-on-apache2-4-debian-9) and 10 pages on Stackoverflow and still can't manage to pass it

Comment: `[ssl:warn] [pid 14236:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name` could it be that your servername missmatch the SSL certificate? why not sohw us also your apache config

Comment: I did not change anything on the apache config, im on localhost using xampp

Comment: this does not answer my question - however since your almost above 20 points, i suggest you join [TheChat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126791/thechat) and we continue there

Comment: cant post the full apache httpd.conf file here.