# Apache Server Hello in SSL Slow

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to debug a problem with SSL in Apache. I've used Wireshark to capture the packets, and I see the client hello message go out, and then about 10 seconds or so later, I get back a  server hello. Once the SSL connection is established, subsequent HTTPS request are faster.

I am using /dev/urandom for entropy, and I think I have plenty available. My CPU load is next to nothing, but I receive about 10 requests/second.

I'm using the stock settings in Apache 2.2.14 on Ubuntu 10.04. My certificate is a SAN certificate from GoDaddy.

What steps should I take to find out why my server takes so long to respond over SSL? HTTP is snappy, but HTTPS is dead slow.

**Edit:**

Here is an image that shows the client hello, and then about 10 seconds later, the server hello:

[image]

Comment: FYI: Apache 2.2.14 is **3 Years Old** has quite a few known vulnerabilities. You should strongly consider upgrading to 2.2.23 (or the latest version available from your distro).

Comment: What does `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` report[?](http://serverfault.com/questions/280623/apache-extremely-slow-initial-handshake-ssl-enabled)

Comment: @Chris S -- what information does that provide an administrator?

Comment: `entropy_avail` is the number of bits of random data available. It should be in the 2000+ range for a normal server. Being under 200 is very near "running out" for a SSL server that commonly requires 64-128 bits of random data per new connection. There's quite a few articles around for gathering more entropy. I'm not sure if Linux uses hardware sources by default, I've seen more than a few articles about daemons necessary (at some point in time) to gather entropy from hardware sources. `urandom` is the non-blocking entropy souce, but I'm not sure OpenSSL will use it...

Answer (score 1):

Increasing MaxClients will most likely fix this problem.

Note that the default value for MaxClients IS 256, so if this change took care of the problem then you probably had a setting for MaxRequestWorkers that was something lower.  Note that MaxClients is the deprecated name and MaxRequestWorkers is the new name, so if you had a smaller MaxRequestWorkers then added a MaxClients later down in the config, the MaxClients value would override your lower MaxRequestWorkers value, fixing the problem.

As far as why this only happened on HTTPS, I suspect it's because browser clients are more aggressive at keeping connections alive when on HTTPS (understandably).  So it is much easier to run out of available clients.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped up the MaxClients in the apache config to 256, reloaded apache, and things improved dramatically. I'm having a hard time believing that was the problem because HTTP was snappy as ever, but HTTPS was slow.

`apache2ctl status` reports "185 requests currently being processed", and the MaxClients setting was 150 before I made the change. So it kind of makes sense, but again, why would HTTP be fast?

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` reports 190.

Apache 2.2.14 is the latest version of apache available for Ubuntu 10.04.